# Use big.Rat with Go to get Abs() value

Tags: go

I am a beginner with Go and a java developer.
I am currently working with big.Rat.

I need to get the `Abs` of a Rat **n** for which I have to write something like

`n.Abs(n)` or something like `big.Rat{}.Abs(n)`

Why didn't go provide something like just `n.Abs()`?
Or am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: go doc math/big.Rat.Abs

Comment: Well, all functions on Rat, Nat, Float in Big work the same way and allow reusing existing variables to reuse their allocated memory.

Comment: I think the question is valid. May be he needs rephrase it to - "Why do go takes an argument to Abs(), when it has the value with the receiver"

Comment: @MangatRaiModi yes exactly. I find that bit weird coming from Java.

Comment: I guess just setting `z.a.neg = false` should be enough in https://golang.org/src/math/big/rat.go?s=9365:9395#L349.

Comment: @Volker I read the docs. But since value already available why does it need another parameter. Doesn't it make code less readable. if I write like a.Abs(b) what does it return. Abs of A or of B.

Comment: @AkhilKNambiar it returns Abs of B, but mutates A to contain that. This is to save memory. I guess better functions would have been A.Abs(), A.Set(B)

Comment: All functions have the same type of signature. This is for consistency and to reduce allocations and there is nothing more to say.

Answer (score 2):

Go's `big` package is concerned with memory allocation when it comes to its function signatures. A `big.Rat` consists of two `big.Int`s which each contain an array of `uint`s. Unlike an `int` (native 32 or 64 bit integer), a `big.Int` must thus be allocated dynamically, depending on its value. For large values this means more elements in the array.

Your proposed function signature `n.Abs()` would mean that a new array of the same size as `n`'s would have to be allocated for this operation. In reality we often have the case that the original `n` is no longer needed, thus we can reuse its existing memory. To allow this, the `Abs` function takes a pointer to an existing `big.Rat` which might be `n` itself. The implementation can now reuse the memory. The caller is now in full control of what memory to use for these operations.

This might not make the nicest API for all use cases, in fact if you just want to do a quick calculation for a few large numbers, on a computer with Gigabytes of RAM, you might have preferred the `n.Abs()` version, but if you do numerically expensive computations with a lot of large numbers, you must be able to control your memory. Imagine doing some image manipulation on a Raspberry for example, where you are more constraint by the available memory. In this case the existing API allows you to be more efficient.